# Jquery jsonp response error - Callback was not return

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

iam have connect API with my server, last version of Query 1.7 it working but now the same code it not show return result, 
this is my code HTML

```js
       $(document).ready(function () {
        refreshSms();
    $("#refresh_sms").click(function (){
        refreshSms();
    });

    function refreshSms(){
    $("#phone").val("");
    $("#sms_code").val("");
    }
    $("#sms_form").submit(function () {
        var sms_code = $("#sms_code");
        var phone = $("#phone");
        if (sms_code.val() == "") {
            alert("text code ");
        } else if (phone.val() == "") {
            alert("type phone");
        } else {
            var params = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://xacthuc.fortune500.com.vn/tem-services/web?another-server=1',
                data: params,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: 'callback',
                jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
                success: function (data){console.log(data);alert(data.message);refreshSms();}});
        }
  return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <div id="sms_pos">
<h4 class="sms_title" style="text-align: center;">test code abc</h4>
<form id="sms_form" method="post" action="#" style="text-align: center; border: solid 1px #CCC;">
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<td>phone</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" value="" id="phone" name="phone">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>text </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" maxlength="70" class="text medium" value="" id="sms_code" name="sms_code">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<button type="submit" id="sms_submit">submit</button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
</body>
```

i dont know how nothing return when i click submit botton

maybe the return params is not right in there

> Blockquote : 
>   data: params,
>                   dataType: 'jsonp',
>                   jsonp: 'callback',
>                   jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
>                   success: function (data){console.log(data);alert(data.message);refreshSms();}});

Comment: Does console returns any error?

Comment: the consle return on debug with SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier, but server has sent result with word

Comment: kindly post result of the ajax request , also post code of the request URL if possible.